# CSS3 text-shadow IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have been trying to find out how this [website](http://kremim.com/) managed to get the text shadow function working so slick in IE 7+.

Perhaps it is using some filter but i cannot see it in the style sheet of the website.
Can someone help me out?

The following image has text shadow effect in ie7

[image: text-shadow ie7+]

Answer (score 0):

They are using backing text, i.e. the same text, offset from the oringial text and a different colour, with a IE filter attribute to blur 
as per this snippet from the site

```
   <h1 style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
        Sağlık &amp; Güzellik Bilgilendirme Sitemize Hoş Geldiniz
        <span class="dummyShadow" id="dummyShadow9" 
              style="
              left: -1px; 
              top: 0px; 
              width: 100%; 
              color: rgb(0,0,0); 
              display: block; 
              filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(
                      PixelRadius=2, 
                      MakeShadow=false, 
                      ShadowOpacity=0.8); 
              position: absolute; 
              z-index: -1;">
                   Sağlık &amp; Güzellik Bilgilendirme Sitemize Hoş Geldiniz
        </span>
    </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please read the mentioned below article you can get few kind of `text-shadow` **IE** filters from here.

I hope this will help you :- 
http://heygrady.com/blog/2011/03/10/css-text-shadows-in-internet-explorer/

```
h1 {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=135,strength=2,color=ff0000);
}
```